# Resize width of select-element by width of sibling element

Tags: html, css

I have a problem of setting the width of a select-element (html). The problem can be broken down to 2 parts:

- The select-element's width = total width of the 2 input-elements.
- When the width of one of the input-elements is changed = width of select-element is automatically adjusted.

Is it possible to solve this with pure CSS only?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="display: inline-block; background: blue;">

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo  </option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>

<input size="8" type="text" value="hej">
<input size="8" type="text" value="hej">

</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**edit**
Note that the input-elements has attribute 'size="8"'. I want them to of that size since the rest of the project have that look. 
Therefore, only the select-element should shrink/grow in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

What I did is placed the two input elements as sibling to the select tag. and made the select tag position absolute with respect to its parent i.e div. This works only when we know / can control the height of the select tag.

I applied padding-top to div which must be equal to the select tag's height.

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0px;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background: blue;">
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input size="8" type="text" value="hej">
    <input size="8" type="text" value="hej">
  </div>
  <br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox would work well for this but couldn't you just set the select to a percentage and then the inputs to half of that percentage?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.select-container {
  width: 100%;
  }
select {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="select-container" style="display: inline-block; background: blue;">

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo  </option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>

<input size="8" type="text" value="hej">
<input size="8" type="text" value="hej">

</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work since the 2 input-elements is wider than the select-element

Comment: I made an edit to my snippet. The reason why they weren't fitting was because the margin/padding/border extends the width past 25%. The way around this is using border-box. There is still a little space between inputs but I believe this has to do with the actual styles being naturally applied to the inputs.

Comment: If you look at your snippet it still doesn't fit... If the div is not an "inline-block" it works. However, it overrides the 'size="8"'-argument and therefore doesn't answer the question (sorry that I was not clear about that in the initial question).